# Spilled water on laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard

By mistake, I spilled some water on my laptop.

The Keyboard is still, sort of, working, but it does some weird things, such as space does page-up, the `s` button it will write `sf` or in the case of `w`, `wr`, and a bunch of stuff like that.

My question is:

Is there any way I can do something like resetting the keyboard, software-wise, not hardware (since I have no way or knowledge about breaking it apart)

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Definitely a hardware problem. The software responsible for your keyboard has not been affected, so there is nothing to reset. Apparently pressing `s` key will also trigger `f` now (and so on), so the best you could do is to set `f` to nothing software-wise. But since more keys were affected, you would probably get an unusable keyboard at the end. The best IMO is to buy a new keyboard...

Comment: Unplug and Let the keyboard dry out for a few days, see it it returns to normal operation. If you put it in the refrigerator it will dry out faster.

Answer (score 3):

## How a keyboard works

The key-board is usually made of a matrix of wires. Each key sits at the intersection of 2 wires. When a key is pressed two wires are connected. [image] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit.

The better ones also have diodes, to stop cross-talk, and allow cording (more than one key to be pressed at a time, without problem). (an alternative to cording, is dedicated lines for shift keys).

## What to do about your problem

From your description of the problems, it seems like two line may have become connected (the wsx column and the rfv column (the diodes may make this bridge one way).

The only solutions are:

- replace key-board
- disable key-board
- fix key-board (this one is unlikely to work)

Comment: Perhaps "wait until the keyboard is bone-dry" works...